# I'm getting an error in my android app where it crashes after I press the button

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I tried implementing a fix that I had followed but go no results, I'm pretty sure it's something small that I'm just not seeing. This is the error from logcat

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.example.ramos.nester, PID: 11297
                                                                          java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method retrieve (MainActivity)(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'guibutt'
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
                                                                              at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4492)
                                                                              at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18568)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Code

```
    package com.example.ramos.nester;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import okhttp3.*;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void insert(View view) {
        // Add the code that you want
        // Or do nothing if you want
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void retrieve(View v) {

        Button guibutt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.guibutt);
        TextView software = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.software);
        TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView last = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.last);
        TextView device = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.device);
        TextView battery = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.battery);

        final String auth = "Bearer c.I1LDweqMS6Fdc3c2gLPcH8Z1W0B6dDVOXDQ9WYZYdyjoULoUubiB59cGn03mDPmXvaJv1i0Qg2H1mHA3QTmdwKOU9BVePV9MfQgKTcAuNnjddtTgIWR7Ngcz6d7ED7d14whkNuTAE3EC7uS4"; // Update with your token

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .authenticator(new Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
                        return response.request().newBuilder()
                                .header("Authorization", auth)
                                .build();
                    }
                })
                .followRedirects(true)
                .followSslRedirects(true)
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://developer-api.nest.com")
                .get()
                .addHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
                .addHeader("authorization", auth)
                .build();
        try {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
            JSONObject devices = json.getJSONObject("devices");
            JSONObject smoke_co_alarms = devices.getJSONObject("smoke_co_alarms");
            JSONObject alarm = smoke_co_alarms.getJSONObject("pBQ6G56_J-C-VMTeIri1Zl3BtVDjEvJ-");


            String softwaretexterino = alarm.getString("software_version");
            String nametexterino = alarm.getString("name");
            String lasttexterino = alarm.getString("last_connection");
            String devicetexterino = alarm.getString("device_id");
            String betterytexterino = alarm.getString("battery_health");

            software.setText(softwaretexterino);
            name.setText(nametexterino);
            last.setText(lasttexterino);
            device.setText(devicetexterino);
            battery.setText(betterytexterino);

            Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    View.OnClickListener myOnlyhandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.guibutt:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.nestapp.MainActivity">

    <Button
            android:text="Click Me For Information"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="36dp" android:id="@+id/guibutt" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:onClick="retrieve (MainActivity)"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/software"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:text="Software Version" android:layout_below="@+id/last"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="Device ID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="45dp" android:id="@+id/device" android:layout_above="@+id/battery"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="38dp" android:id="@+id/name"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="false" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="Battery Health"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="53dp" android:id="@+id/battery"
            android:layout_above="@+id/last" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/last"
            android:text="Last Time Period of Connection"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can I see your layout xml file for this activity?

Comment: the manifest or the main?

Comment: im referring to R.layout.activity_main. the manifest is not a layout file. you can check all your layouts in res/layout folder

Comment: Just edited it in

Answer (score 0):

I'm new here and my experience with Android is somewhat limited. However, I think that without posting your code it is more difficult to tell what is causing the crash (at least for someone like me).  Adding your code might motivate other people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can figure out from the code you have posted above, this error is popping up due to unavailability of onClick method. I faced a similar problem once where had made use of View class and not used onClick method. Try adding setOnClickListener function in place of retrieve function. It should resolve your error. This is the syntax to make use of View class and OnClick method to detect button click.

```
btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.firstButton);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        //Code goes inside this function.
    }
});
```

If this does not help, it would be better if you post the XML code of the activity also.

Comment: Where exactly do I place this? I also re-edited the code again, I posted the wrong version of my code -.- I did this 3 times

Comment: Have you added Internet permission in Android Manifest file?

Comment: And I did not tell you to add the code inside the retrieve function. I said you can swap the retrieve function with function above if you are looking to do something on the click of a button.